# How to write forget password for this requirement

Tags: php

I have three table :tutorregistration,studentregistration,Instituteregistration.Now I want to write forget password code for this:I know how to send mail for this,guide my logic approach is correct. if it is wrong,give me a correct code.

```
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
<strong>Email</strong>
<input type="text" name="email" value="" class="buttonlength"/>
<strong>Password</strong>
<input type="password" name="password" value="" class="buttonlength"/>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="student" />Student <input type="radio" name="type" value="tutor" />Tutor <input type="radio" name="type" value="institute" />Institute</td>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn" id="submit"/>
</form>



      In forget.php file:
        <form name="f1" action="" method="post">
        enter email:<input type="text" name="email" value=''/>
                     <input type="submit" name="Submit"/>
        </form>

    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $sqlstudent=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  studentregistration WHERE  email='".$email."'") or die(mysql_error());
     $row_rsinfo=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlstudent))
    $sqltutor=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  tutorregistration WHERE  email='".$email."'") or die(mysql_error());
  $row_rsinfo=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqltutor))
    $sqlinstitute=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  Instituteregistration WHERE  email='".$email."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsinfo=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlinstitute))
    if(count($row_rsinfo)>=1)
    {
    //mail work here
    }
    }
    ?>
So far what  I have tried.I have given,I know how to send mail for registered mail id.Here I want to know how to check which query is executing, check and give me the answer for this.
```

Comment: You're missing a bunch of semicolons.

Comment: "if it is wrong,give me a correct code." - I think you've misunderstood the whole concept with SO.

Comment: Sorry I will learn .I don't know how to handle this. I am new to php

Comment: Frank can you guide me where I went wrong . I will add semicolon at the end of each line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this for forgot password.

enter email:

```
 <?php
        if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
        {
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $sqlstudent=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  studentregistration WHERE  email='".$email."'") or die(mysql_error());
         $row_rsinfo=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlstudent));
  if(count($row_rsinfo)==1)
        {
        //mail work here
        }
        $sqltutor=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  tutorregistration WHERE  email='".$email."'") or die(mysql_error());
      $row_rsinfo=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqltutor));
    if(count($row_rsinfo)==1)
        {
        //mail work here
        }
        $sqlinstitute=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  Instituteregistration WHERE  email='".$email."'") or die(mysql_error());
        $row_rsinfo=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlinstitute))

        if(count($row_rsinfo)==1)
        {
        //mail work here
        }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer.here $_POST['type']=='student' I did not get from forget  password page . just I am asking only enter email id. check and guide me once again thanks lot

Comment: i know but you should ask user type like you ask in login

Comment: OK thanks. is there is any way without asking there type, generally In any website they will ask only enter the email. here IN my requirement. I made like this and my db also in different table, why I have created like that for all registration from label is different so for edit and delete that is ok. if any way please guide me.

Comment: i just edited my answer. now it will work on your needs.

Comment: Thanks lot, One more clarification with you, I have not encrypted any one password while sending to db. what I planned here is just I will send back there registered password to there registered emailid. is there anything wrong in it.

Comment: Because most of the thread I read use md5 for encrypt. some thread had mentioned they will break md5 also.I need your suggestion here,so at beginning point . I will send the registered password. for time being I will send the registered password later on .after I got 5000 registered user I will send the activation link to ask a new password. with md5 stuff.

Comment: use base_64 for encryption if you want to send password not the link

Comment: It means for encryption base_64 , for forget password  I need to send the link to change the password for registered user am i correct.

Comment: sorry I could not find any link

Comment: base_64 is for if you want to encrypt registered  password. because you can decrypt also to send user password.
for the link it is tricky process. You send the user a link like this 
http://example.com/urfile.php?reference=454dsfdsf5644ds
this number is md5(454dsfdsf5644ds).
this is also store in your database for check the user come from your link or not.
if user change this password then this md5() code will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks lot once again thanks for your valuable suggestion I too learnt lot in this going forward I hope I do better for my website